# CakePHP Cache Config always reverts to File (from Memcache or APC)

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

Firstly both Memcache and APC are installed successfully using PECL (and are verified as working) on my Macbook Pro dev server running PHP 5.3.15

I've just baked a test Cake 2.2.2 app. In `Config/core.php` I have the following:

```
/**
 * Pick the caching engine to use.  If APC is enabled use it.
 * If running via cli - apc is disabled by default. ensure it's available and enabled in this case
 *
 */
$engine = 'File';
if (extension_loaded('apc') && function_exists('apc_dec') && (php_sapi_name() !== 'cli' || ini_get('apc.enable_cli'))) {
    $engine = 'Apc';
}
if (extension_loaded('memcache') && php_sapi_name() !== 'cli') {
    $engine = 'Memcache';
}

// In development mode, caches should expire quickly.
$duration = '+999 days';
if (Configure::read('debug') >= 1) {
    $duration = '+10 seconds';
}

// Prefix each application on the same server with a different string, to avoid Memcache and APC conflicts.
$prefix = 'mcmyapp_';

/**
 * Configure the cache used for general framework caching.  Path information,
 * object listings, and translation cache files are stored with this configuration.
 */
Cache::config('_cake_core_', array(
    'engine' => $engine,
    'prefix' => $prefix . 'cake_core_',
    'path' => CACHE . 'persistent' . DS,
    'serialize' => ($engine === 'File'),
    'duration' => $duration
));

/**
 * Configure the cache for model and datasource caches.  This cache configuration
 * is used to store schema descriptions, and table listings in connections.
 */
Cache::config('_cake_model_', array(
    'engine' => $engine,
    'prefix' => $prefix . 'cake_model_',
    'path' => CACHE . 'models' . DS,
    'serialize' => ($engine === 'File'),
    'duration' => $duration
));


Cache::config('default', array(
    'engine' => $engine,
    'serialize' => ($engine === 'File'),
    'duration'=>$duration,
    'prefix'=>$prefix,
));

debug(Cache::settings());
```

The output of the above final debug() is:

```
array(
    'prefix' => '*****',
    'engine' => 'Memcache',
    'serialize' => false,
    'duration' => (int) 10,
    'servers' => array(
        (int) 0 => '127.0.0.1'
    ),
    'compress' => false,
    'persistent' => true,
    'probability' => (int) 100,
    'groups' => array()
)
```

So in `core.php` it appears that Cake wants to use Memcache for its caching engine.

However, when I visit `localhost/myapp/pages/home` in my browser, CakePHP's default, freshly-baked welcome page greets me, informing me that `The FileEngine is being used for core caching`

Anywhere else in my app (other than in `core.php`) if I `debug(Cache::settings())`, I get the following:

```
array(
    'prefix' => '*****',
    'engine' => 'File',
    'serialize' => false,
    'duration' => (int) 10,
    'servers' => array(
        (int) 0 => '127.0.0.1'
    ),
    'compress' => false,
    'persistent' => true,
    'probability' => (int) 100,
    'groups' => array()
)
```

Basically, CakePHP appears to revert to File for caching, ignoring my configuration in `core.php` to use Memcache... unless I've done something wrong here??!

I've tried this with `Configure::write('debug', 0)` and `Configure::write('debug', 1)`.

I should mention that with the above, both APC and Memcache extensions are enabled in `php.ini`.

Any help would be gratefully received, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memcached should be on some port, default one is 11211 (check)... So your config tries to connect to Memcached, fails and reverts back to default (File) cache...

Try:

```
Cache::config('default', array(
    'engine' => 'Memcache',
    'duration'=> 3600, 
    'probability'=> 100, 
    'servers' => array('127.0.0.1:11211') <<<<==
));
```